# how to create multidimensional, dynamically defined array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

i know how to create a single-dimensional, dynamically defined array

```
 string *names = new string[number]; //number specified by the user
```

however, when i try to make it multidimensional

```
 string *names = new string[number][number]; //doesn't work
```

it doesn't work.  what gives?  i found this http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/63/ but am completely confused by what they are saying.  anyone care to explain?  thanks so much.

Comment: have you tried: string **names = new string[number][number];

Comment: just tried it now, no luck :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[C++\] How do I declare a 2d array using new?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/c-how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-using-new)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to provide some explanations to example from your link:

```
// To dynamically allocate two-dimensional array we will allocate array of pointers to int first. 
// Each pointer will represent a row in your matrix.
// Next step we allocate enough memory for each row and assign this memory for row pointers.

const int rows = 4; //number of rows in your matrix
const int cols = 4; //number of columns in your matrix

// declaration
int ** a; 

/* allocating memory for pointers to rows. Each row will be a dynamically allocated array of int */
a = new int*[rows];
/* for each row you allocate enough memory to contain cols elements. cols - number of columns*/ 
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
   a[i] = new int[cols];
```

Comment: thank you so much for this.  i'm currently digesting...but in the meanwhile, may i ask what int **a is as opposed to int *a?  thankyou.

Comment: yeah, it is a pointer to pointer to int. It means, that if we have `int **ppint`, then '*ppint' is a pointer to int. And **ppint is int. We can for example do this: `int *pint = *ppint`.

Comment: thanks.  i'm still confused as to how to access the data in the multidimensional array.  doing cout << elements[0][3]; doesn't work, for example (it prints out the address i believe, which makes sense i guess since they're pointers and pointers store addresses)

Answer (score 0):

The memory layout of single-dimension array (let's say with three elements) looks like,

```
names ------> [0] [1] [2]
```

And the two-dimensional array (let's say with 3 X 3 elements) would look like,

```
names ------> [0] --> [0] [1] [2] 
              [1] --> [0] [1] [2]
              [2] --> [0] [1] [2]
               ^
               |
           this is an array of pointers
```

i.e. two dimensional array is array of pointers to arrays, therefore you would need **names in first place.

```
string **names = new string*[number]; // allocating space for array of string pointers
```

Now, you want each element of this array of string pointers to point to an array of strings.

Therefore, you would need to do

```
for(int i = 0; i < number, i++) {
   names[i] = new string[number];
}
```

I hope this helps to understand it better.